# How to use custom prelude with stack ghci?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I added a custom Prelude, which is working well for `stack build` and `stack test`. However, `stack ghci` does not like it, as it seems to be trying to load all of these at once:

```
$ stack --nix ghci
XXX-0.1.0.0: initial-build-steps (lib + exe)
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: XXX

* * * * * * * *

Error: Multiple files use the same module name:
       * Prelude found at the following paths
         * XXX/server/Prelude.hs (XXX:exe:XXX.exe)
         * XXX/src/Prelude.hs (XXX:lib)
         * XXX/tests/Prelude.hs (XXX:exe:tests.exe)
* * * * * * * *

Not attempting to start ghci due to these duplicate modules.
```

First, to explain the three different `Prelude.hs` files: they are identical as two of them are symbolic links to the third file; I hadn't thought of a better way to do this without possibly exposing my `Prelude.hs` to dependent libraries.

A possible workaround would be to tell stack/ghci to only load the library code (under `src` in this case), or better yet, be able to tell it to skip particular `.hs` files on loading.

Comment: If stack supports them (?), you could use [internal libraries](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#sublibs) to avoid duplicating `Prelude` without exporting it.

Comment: Using internal libraries seems to get further along  but I get `<command line>: cannot satisfy -package prelude` when doing e.g. `stack --nix ghci -v --ghc-options -XNoImplicitPrelude --main-is XXX:exe:XXX.exe` (the `-v`) didn't seem to show any more information relevant to the issue, and adding `-XNoImplicitPrelude` didn't change hte result either.